# PHP - BUG with filter_var and FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT

Tags: php, range, filter-var

I think there is a bug in this filter_var or maybe I'm doing something wrong:
Try this:

```
        $options = array(
            'options' => array(
                'default' => 3,
                'min_range' => 1000.0,
                'max_range' => 5000.6,
            )
        );

  $VariableValue2 = 5698;
  $VariableValue4 = 5698.2;

  $chicco3 = filter_var($VariableValue2, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);
  $chicco4 = filter_var($VariableValue4, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, $options);
```

It suppose to don't validate it...   Infact the value:  5698 is greater than 5000.6!!!!
But with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT it work FINE!!   It return 3 that is the default value in case it don't validate it...   PERFECT...

Instead, with FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT it validate it...   It return 5698.2!!!   I'm doing something wrong???

Thank you to everybody...

Samuele

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php); it looks like you're using the wrong options with the filter. The `min_range` and `max_range` options are for the `filter_validate_int` filter.

By the way, if you're just checking for the size of a number, it probably is easier to use some sort of

```
if( ( $number > 1000 ) && ( $number < 5000.6 ) )
    // do stuff;
```

mechanism instead.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot...  I think you're right...  But I thought it use the same options...   So I can not validate the range of a float with the function:  FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT ?

It look like very strange that with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT you can do it and with FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT you can NOT do it...

Anyway I will do it by me...

Thanks again...   :)

Comment: It has been added in 7.4.0!

Answer (score 9):

Before 7.4, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT did not accept a range option. Check the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: Update: `min_range` and `max_range` options are now available in PHP >= 7.4.0 https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.0